# ". . . . , by which time she'll have left."

Tags: relative-clauses

"I won't be back until seven, by which time she'll have left."

I'm a native speaker, so I have no trouble understanding meaning. But, according to the grammar rules I've learned, the relative clause should be written as "by which she'll have left." What rule(s) am I missing? Why does "time" or "point" need to be included here?

Thanks.

Comment: _By which she'll have left_ doesn't make sense, does it? By which what?

Comment: It could be said in an informal dialogue. "Which" refers to "seven", so we understand 'she'll have left by seven'.

Comment: by which and by which time are not the same meaning.

Comment: They can be in this case. I don't see any real problem with it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have written my question differently. I'm wondering why the word "time" is included in that sentence. If I were speaking, I too would include that word. But, from what I've read, the relative pronoun "which" is being used here to refer back to "seven". Thus, grammatically/logically speaking, isn't "by which time" redundant?

Comment: Please include the grammar rules which have led to your conclusion.

Comment: It just isn't idiomatic to refer to a time of day as _which_ without adding _time_.

Comment: Thanks, Kate. I was kind of thinking that was the answer, though I was hoping it wasn't.